# Collection of APIs making up one Application - How to manage?

Tags: c#, web-applications, api, visual-studio, project-structure

We have inherited an application that is made up of small .NET web API's. Each API has its own Visual Studio SLN and git repo. All of the APIs are published to one folder ("All") and that folder is hosted on IIS with each of the APIs as a separate application on the same website and app pool. The folder with the published APIs also has a git repo.

The one exception is the 'CommonOps', which is a class library that all other APIs share. The dll is published into a common folder.

Everything works for the most part, and I don't want to create unnecessary work (or update for update's sake).

The problem is when we find a bug. For instance, if something in the CommonOps needs updating, we need to create a branch in both, the CommonOps and the "All" repo. Then publish the updated CommonOps (pull request and merge), to "All" and then pull request and merge "All". If other people work on "All" at the same time, pull requests can lead to marathon merge conflicts.

What would be the best approach to unifying the whole lot into one repo, or should I leave well enough alone? If the latter, what would work best for a workflow when we need to change one of the APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is the 'correct' way to manage your APIs

- Delete the All repo
- Publish the CommonOps library as a nuget package
- Consume CommponOps nuget in the various APIs
- Publish each API in its own website rather than Applications under a single WebSite

When you update CommonOps, publish a new version of the package, feature branch those APIs requiring the new version, update the package, merge, build and deploy those APIs

Comment: That sounds great, but it would mean that every API (every website) would need to be bound to a different port. Or is there a way around that?

Comment: yes, host headers. they have been around a while

Comment: or multiple ips per box if you like

Comment: or do the ports, but hide them behind your load balancer

Comment: or have one VM per site (which is also something you are supposed to do, but might be overkill for you)

Comment: I haven't dealt with host headers for a while, but that's a very good point. I wouldn't want to use multiple ports or IPs. VMs are an overkill (I also looked at dockerising the lot, which was also overkill). Thank you, I like this idea. (Sorry, I can't upvote because of my rep score)

Comment: or use docker and you can do all of the above in a few configuration files